# Android creating a thumbnails layout

Tags: java, android

I'm inflating a layout in a dialog, this layout shows many thumbnails of an eBook (96 ImageViews).
When I click on a certain ImageView it will take me to a certain page. The point is I'm having a 96 "if" statements so I want to make the code much more simpler. I'm asking for an advice or help to achieve this goal. Here is my code :

Thumbnails layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#b8c9bc"
     android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumblayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:visibility="visible" >

               <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="0.9" >

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical" >

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_gravity="right"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh1" />

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh2" />

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh3" />

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh4" />

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh5" />

          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .


                            <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView101"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_gravity="left"
                           android:src="@drawable/thumbpageh97" />
                   </LinearLayout>

               </ScrollView>


                   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/but"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#e2edd3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>







</LinearLayout>
```

Java code :

```
       thumbbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.thumblayout);


            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            wmlp.x = 10;   //x position
            wmlp.y = 10;   //y position



            dialog.show();


   final Button cancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   final ImageView thumbpage1=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   final ImageView thumbpage2=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
   final ImageView thumbpage3=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
   final ImageView thumbpage96=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView100);
   final ImageView thumbpage97=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView101);

   cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.hide();
    //   x=hsv.getScrollX();
    //     y=hsv.getScrollY();
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "X="+String.valueOf(x)+" and Y="+String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

   thumbpage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page1);
        pagenumber=1;
        int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
        int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
        pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

          myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            checkMemoButtonStatus();
            myDbHelper.close();
    }
});


   thumbpage2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page2);
            pagenumber=2;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page3);
            pagenumber=3;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page4);
            pagenumber=4;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page5);
            pagenumber=5;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page6);
            pagenumber=6;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page7);
            pagenumber=7;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page8);
            pagenumber=8;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

   thumbpage9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page9);
            pagenumber=9;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

              myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                checkMemoButtonStatus();
                myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });

                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .




   thumbpage96.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page96);
            pagenumber=96;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText(String.valueOf(p1)+" - "+String.valueOf(p2));

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            checkMemoButtonStatus();
            myDbHelper.close();
        }
    });
   thumbpage97.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.page97);
            pagenumber=97;
            int p1=(pagenumber*2)-2;
            int p2=(pagenumber*2)-1;
            pages.setText("192");

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            checkMemoButtonStatus();
            myDbHelper.close();
        }
    }); 

//          visible++;
//          
//          if(visible==1)
//          {
//              thumblayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
//              thumblayout.setVisibility(0);
//          }
//          else
//          {
//              thumblayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
//              visible=0;
//               
//          }





            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I've searched about using a customized listview with images, also I've searched about getting the position of the view in the scrollview, but it didn't give much help, thank you

Comment: From what I see your view is quite uniform So why don't you use listview? it much more simpler and faster :)

Comment: See my answer for a first step if you have problem

Answer (score 2):

So I won't provide you all the code but I will try to lead you how to use `ListView` to solve your problem.

So first you will need to replace the whole ScrollView with a ListView and then create an ArrayAdapter for the ListView with custom view

this is an example for an ArrayAdapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private static ViewHolder viewHolder;
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<String> urls;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_newsfeed, urls);
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_child, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.imageItem.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
    final String url = urls.get(position);
    //SETUP THE IMAGE HERE
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

}

And then you can pass the URL or Drawable name or whatever image source you have.
If you are using URL I recommends you to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) it's easy to use imageloader library.

If you have any other question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

try this its a scrollview .. add an id to the scrollviews linear layout. `android:id="@+id/addlay"`. and reference it in java.`LinearLayout addlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addlay);`. after loop through the 96 images using any loop proccess -(eg. for loop).. and programmaticaly create an imageview and add it to the linearlayout you referenced.. you can set id with their loop values and also set the url to visit as a string tag..to the imageview

```
 for(int i =0; i < 96; i++){ //you can use  ++1 so to start form one..its your choice
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setId(i);
        iv.setTag((String)"url");
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.getTag(); // you get your url...
        }
    });
        addlay.addView(iv);
    }
```

after this you can respond to other events or get what image is flirting now with the user with this`addlay.getFocusedChild()`,. to get a flirting view id `addlay.getFocusedChild().getId()` same way for the tag..and so forth..

Note: there might be silly code errors..cos i jux wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this purely in XML won't get you far. What if you want to change the properties of the ImageViews? What if the number of Images changes?

To create a grid or list of similar items use a **GridView**. It can be filled with items by **Adapters** or manually in your code. GridViews with only one column behave like lists.

See the **Android Tutorial** on how to setup a GridView with Images per Adapter:

[Android GridView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

In your case you need at least XML file: The page with the GridView. You may also use another XML defining your ImageViews and inflate them in the ImageAdapter, but in the Tutorial it's done by code, so we stick with it.

The naming of the Adapter is just a convention, if you return other Views or ViewGroups to the caller, you should name it so (like MyCardAdapter, when using cards).

Here's your main page:

main_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#b8c9bc"
     android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumblayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:visibility="visible" >

               <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="0.9" >
                   <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:columnWidth="90dp"
                        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The important code in the ImageAdapter from the Tutorial is the Method getView(..):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

This Method is called for every Item in your Adapter, where the Number of Items is defined in getCount(). In getView() you create your ImageView either from XML or by Code and return it to the Caller. You get the position of the view, probably a convertView and a parent ViewGroup. Use the *position* to get the correct Image Resource and probably set a Tag to the ImageView, so you can identify it even without the GridView.onItemClickListener.

If the convertView is not null, you should use it instead of creating a new ImageView. Speeds up the GridView Performance by a great Margin and also reduces the Memory Footprint of your App.

The Line

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

sets the Size of the Thumbnails, you probably want to put in some Resource Dimension Value to adjust for bigger Screens.

The great Thing about GridView is that you don't have to take any Measures to identify  the Item been clicked. The GridView does it for you.

Thus setting a Click Handler on the GridView is all you need to do (again, Code from the Tutorial):

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Another advantage of GridView is that it adjusts its grid to the available space. This is done by specifying *android:numColumns="auto_fit"*. You can put any number of colums here if you want to keep it static, though.